# CParserError when reading csv file into python Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a big csv file (around 17GB) into python Spyder using pandas module. Here is my code

```
data =pd.read_csv('example.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

But I keep getting CParserError error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-3993cadd40d6>", line 1, in <module>
data =pd.read_csv('newsall.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 325, in _read
return parser.read()

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 815, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1314, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 805, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:8748)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 827, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:9003)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 881, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:9731)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 868, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:9602)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:23325)

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

I am aware there are some discussions about the issue, but it seems quite specific and varies from case to case. Does anyone can help me out here?

I'm using python 3 on windows system. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by ResMar, I tried the following code

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
reader = pd.read_csv('newsall.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', chunksize = 10000)
for chunk in reader:
   data.append(chunk, ignore_index=True)
```

But it returns nothing with

```
data.shape
Out[12]: (0, 0)
```

Then I tried the following code

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
reader = pd.read_csv('newsall.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', chunksize = 10000)
for chunk in reader:
   data = data.append(chunk, ignore_index=True)
```

It again shows run out of memory error, here is the trackback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-23-ee9021fcc9b4>", line 3, in <module>
for chunk in reader:

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 795, in __next__
return self.get_chunk()

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 836, in get_chunk
return self.read(nrows=size)

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 815, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

File "I:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1314, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 805, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:8748)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 839, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:9208)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 881, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:9731)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 868, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:9602)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:23325)

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be pretty obvious what your error is: the computer runs out of memory. The file itself is 17GB, and as a rule of thumb `pandas` will take up roughly double that much space when it reads the file. So you'd need *around* 34GB of RAM to read this data in directly.

Most computers these days have 4, 8, or 16 GB; a few have 32. Your computer just runs out of memory and C kills the process when you do.

You can get around this by reading in your data in chunks, doing whatever you want to do on it with each segment in turn. See the [`chunksize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter to `pd.read_csv` for more details on that, but you'll basically want something that looks like:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv("...", chunksize=10000):
    do_something()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just want to read the data in as a dataframe, what should be code for do_something?

Comment: That's for you to determine.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edited question? It still delivers error.